# Django request.session does not resolve

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-sessions

I have a ManyToMany relation between 2 of my models in the same app. This looks like following:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    eventID = models.CharField(deafult = random_eventID)
    signal = models.ManyToManyField(Signal)
    ....
    ....
```

Now, in my Form (using ModelForm) my **eventID** field is already populated with the **eventID** every time i refresh the page (because it gets a new **random_eventID** every time i refresh the page). 
This way when, in my forms i select to add a new signal (I want to be able to add signals when i create an event)...it goes to a different view. I save the event and when i return back to the Event page, the **eventID** is changed again. I want to have all the data which the user has already filled/selected in the form to be present when it returns back to the Event page after adding lots of different stuff.

**Solutions i thought of :**

1 - I cannot make changes to my model so as to include another column and save the Event before going to another page & later retrieve it back.

2 - Using sessions i save all the data already present in all the fields an later retrieve it back..( This way HTTP is no more stateless, but it serves my purpose.)

3 - Will Ajax help in doing any update (which i don't understand it will)

I tried it using session and came cross this silly error, which i am not able to resolve.

**views.py**

```
def create(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        form .save()
        del request.session['event_id']
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Event')
    else:
        event_session = request.session.get('event_id')
        if event_session is not None:
            form = EiEventForm(initial={'eventID' : event_session}
        else:
            form = EventForm()
            request.session['event_id'] = form('eventID').value()
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = form
    return render_to_response('event.html', args)
```

With the above, after debugging i do not get the current value in the eventID field..I tried some other ways as well but with no success.

The request.GET.get('eventID') returns None..How can i get the values from my field ?

Also, is there a better way to accomplish the desired result except sessions.

Any help would be great help!

Comment: You are using eventID and event_id as keys in request.session. Your code has some syntax errors, I don't know if they are TYPOs from copy&paste or your code is wrong.

Comment: @esauro Yes, it was a typo error. I corrected it.